# My multiDimentional Array code is not working correctly

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

My code below gives me unexpected output.
What I'm trying to do is create a multi dimentional array, and then populate it with values of x, y, z inside a loop. But for some reason, it fills only the "maximum" value of x, y, z in all elements. Instead it should fill the current value. If you uncomment the first System.out line, you'll see the result I actually want.

```
public class Test{

public static void main( String args[] ){


int[][] a= new int[ 150 ][3];

int[] val = new int[3];
int increment =0;

for( int x=0; x<10; ++x ){
for( int y=0; y<5; ++y ){
for( int z=0; z<3; ++z ){

val[0]=x; val[1]=y; val[2]=z;

a[ increment ]=val; 
++increment;
//System.out.println( x+" "+y+" "+z+" "+ increment )

} } }// for

for( int s=0; s<increment; ++s ){ System.out.println( a[ s ][0]+" "+ a[ s ][1]+" "+ a[ s ][2]+" "+ s ); }


}//main
}//class
```

my output:

```
9 4 4 0
9 4 4 1
9 4 4 increment
```

expected output:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1
0 0 2 2
...
0 1 1 3
0 1 2 4
    .
    .
    .
upto so on
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: No, in your method it's just incrementing the "increment". What I'm trying to do is x y z increment. (Increment is just to see where I am in the array. that is not important) So in my loop, x=0, then y=0, then z runs 3 times, then x=0 y=1 and z starts over. z reaches 3, then y gets increased by 1 again. This continues. Finally y reaches 5, then x gets increased by 1 and so on.

Comment: Please add this line soon after ++increment and you'll see the output I want: System.out.println( x+" "+y+" "+z+" "+increment );

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: now it's working as per last comment of @SumitKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the values in `val`, but then you set a reference of `val` in each cell of `a`. Thus, when the value of `val` is changed, the values **all** the references change, and hence they all become `9,4,4`. the last value is `s` which keeps on incrementing in your loop. Thus you get that output.

To get the required output, just reset `val` before each iteration. Add this line:

```
val = new int[3];
```

as the first line in your innermost for loop.

Comment: oh Many thanks. This was driving me crazy. I'll keep this in mind from here on.